# How do I implement From<T> for Option<U> in Rust?

Tags: rust

Assuming I have an enum as:

```rust
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
}
```

...where I want to implement something like this:

```rust
impl From<char> for Option<Foo> {
    fn from(chr: char) -> Self {
        match chr {
            'A' => Some(Foo::A),
            'B' => Some(Foo::B),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

This is currently illegal since `Option` is out of my own crate, it is owned by `std`. The compiler error is:

```
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
define and implement a trait or new type instead rustc(E0117)
```

As in the case I have shown above, in some cases, I'd like to have `None` instead of `Some`. Is there a way to implement a `From` that I am able to get `Option<U>` instead of `U` itself?

---

## Environment

- Rust 1.62.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you actually want in this scenario is to implement the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait instead.

For example (ideally you'd make a proper `Error` type rather than a `str`):

```rust
impl TryFrom<char> for Foo {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(chr: char) -> Result<Foo, Self::Error> {
        match chr {
            'A' => Ok(Foo::A),
            'B' => Ok(Foo::B),
            _ => Err("can't convert character to Foo"),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh dangit! How do I forget such a thing? | SO limits me to mark this as answer in 9 minutes. I will mark it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's much better. Here I was digging through RFCs to find out if `Option` is a fundamental type, but the solution is right here in front of us.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo If it would a simple `impl` will work (and no need to find an RFC, you can just look at the source code).